# Открытие файлов require и fwrite

Tags: php

Почему require открывает файл а fwrite вызывает ошибку? Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in

```
require dirname(__FILE__).'/../logs/log.php';
function addLog($var)
{
    $file = dirname(__FILE__).'/../logs/log.php';
    fwrite($file, $var);
}
```

Comment: Почему минусы? Что не так? Если путь не корректный ошибку должен вызвать require, но он ошибку не вызывает.

Comment: fwrite — Бинарно-безопасная запись в файл   . 
fwrite() записывает содержимое string в файловый поток handle.  Перед fwrite файл сначала через fopen() откройте  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fwrite.php

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что перед тем как задать вопрос нужно читать документацию по используемым функциям

Answer (score 1):

Минусы потому, что Вам надо начать с чтения основ: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fwrite.php

Функция fwrite первым параметром требует ссылку на ресурс, куда будет записываться информация.

Answer (score 0):

Забыл $file = fopen($file, 'a');